# background image doesn't appear but background colours do

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am doing a parallax site and it works perfectly on desktops. However, when I viewed it on iPad or iPhone, background images for images that are fixed do not appear. However, when I use a coloured background, the bg colour appears.

I have tried so many ways to solve my problem and I am at my wits end so any help would be good..

the staging site: www.youcanuseit.com/responsive/dark

Comment: What you try?can show u coding?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a simplified version of the code that causes the problem rather then expecting us to ick our way through your production site.

Comment: I had the same problem on a site I did that used a very large image - I think the ipad has a limit to the size of background image it will download

Answer (score 0):

It may help -

```
#home {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

delete screen.css line 178

```
background: #CCC;
```